# Discord bot reactions array

Tags: c#, discord, bots, discord.net

Im trying to get a specific reaction by index 0 of the reactions array:

```
   private async void reset(IUserMessage message)
   {
       message.Reactions.ElementAt(0);
   }
```

But when i do this i dont see the count or emoji variable that [discord documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5ssN.png) says it should contain. Any idea on how i can get the emoji variable from a specific reaction based on index?

Regards,
Jelle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your IUserMessage also implements IMessage, but the below solution works for an IMessage. You can change an IUserMessage to an IMessage using `message as IMessage`.

`IMessage.Emotes` ([docs](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.IMessage.html#Discord_IMessage_Reactions)) contains a dictionary of IEmote, ReactionMetadata. You can use this dictionary to get reaction metadata based on the index or the IEmote you're looking for. [ReactionMetadata](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.ReactionMetadata.html?q=ReactionMetadata) contains ReactionCount which is the number of reactions with that emote.

If you want to know the users that reacted, you should use the `IMessage.GetReactionUsersAsync(IEmote, Int32, RequestOptions)` method ([docs](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.IMessage.html#Discord_IMessage_GetReactionUsersAsync_Discord_IEmote_System_Int32_Discord_RequestOptions_)).